# J2ME Nokia 5800 emulator

Tags: netbeans, java-me, emulation, s60

I'm looking for Nokia 5800 emulator for Netbeans.
Where can i find one?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with nokia 5800 symbian version and you can download from [nokia symbian SDK.](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/ec866fab-4b76-49f6-b5a5-af0631419e9c/S60_All_in_One_SDKs.html) Nokia 5800 is symbian 5th edition. They released nokia n97 emulator SDK for symbian 5th edition. You can use that emulator for this. If you want to test on nokia 5800 real time means you can go with [nokia RDA devices.](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/)